# Post data on server using volley

Tags: java, android, string, android-layout

I am sending some data on server using Volley. Also I have a Java class name `SpeakerBean` where I defined all the parameters for whom value is coming from server, and where I post values on server that is one different class name connect. Now my problem is that in connect class I have to send one of the value of `SpeakerBean` name `speaker_id` internally with parameters of connect class, but I don't understand how to do that because I do not use control/widget (textbox, editbox) for `speaker_id`. So how to pass this id with values I am post to server?

**My code:**

This is connect class to post values on server

```
 public class ConnectWithSpeaker extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

 LinearLayout linear_layoutcontainer;
 Toolbar toolbar;


 String url = Constants.SUBMIT_API;
 public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
 public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
 public static final String KEY_MOBILE = "mobile";
 public static final String KEY_COMPANY = "company";
 public static final String KEY_SPEAKERID = "speaker_id";

 String s_id;
 private EditText u_name;
 private EditText u_email;
 private EditText u_mobile;
 private EditText u_company;
 private Button submit;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_connect_with_speaker);
     linear_layoutcontainer = (LinearLayout)   findViewById(R.id.linear_layoutcontainer);
     toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.customtoolbar);
     TextView title = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.title);
     title.setText("Connect with Speakers");
     toolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             finish();
         }
     });
     u_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
     u_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
     u_mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobile);
     u_company = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.compny_name);
     submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.connect);
     submit.setOnClickListener(this);
 }

 private void submitdetails() {
     final String name = u_name.getText().toString().trim();   //trim()  remove spaces after&before string
     final String email = u_email.getText().toString().trim();
     final String mobile = u_mobile.getText().toString().trim();
     final String company = u_company.getText().toString().trim();
     final String speaker_id =s_id;


     SpeakersBean sb_obj=new SpeakersBean();
        sb_obj = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("speaker");
        sb_obj.setSpeaker_id(sb_obj.getSpeaker_id().toString().trim());   
       //getting null
       // sb_obj.setSpeaker_id(s_id);
       //s_id =sb_obj.getSpeaker_id();

     Toast.makeText(ConnectWithSpeaker.this, "submit details",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     CustomJSONObjectRequest request2 = new   CustomJSONObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new
 Response.Listener<String>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(String response) {
             if (response.trim().equals("success")) {
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your request is proceed, we will update you with further updates.",
  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
         }
     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                     Toast.makeText(ConnectWithSpeaker.this,  volleyError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 }
             }) {
         @Override
         protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
             Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
             params.put(KEY_NAME, name);
             params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
             params.put(KEY_MOBILE, mobile);
             params.put(KEY_COMPANY, company);
            // params.put(KEY_SPEAKERID, speaker_id);   //pass speaker id too with these parameters coming from speaker_api
             return params;
         }
     };
     RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
     requestQueue.add(request2);
 }
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
     if (v == submit)
     {
         if (TextUtils.isEmpty(u_name.getText().toString())) {
            // u_name.setError("Enter Name");
             u_name.requestFocus();
         }
         if (TextUtils.isEmpty(u_email.getText().toString()))
         {
            // u_email.setError("Enter Email");
             u_email.requestFocus();
         }
         if((TextUtils.isEmpty(u_mobile.getText().toString()))||(u_mobile.length()<10||u_mobile.length()>15))
         {
             u_mobile.setError("Enter valid Mobile No");
             u_mobile.requestFocus();
         }
         if (TextUtils.isEmpty(u_company.getText().toString()))
         {
            // u_company.setError("Enter Company Name");
             u_company.requestFocus();
         } else {
             submitdetails();
         }
    /* if(v==submit){
     submitdetails();
     }*/

     }
 } }
```

This is my `SpeakerBean` class

```
 public class SpeakersBean implements Parcelable{
 @SerializedName("speaker_id")
 private String speaker_id;

 @SerializedName("name")
 private String name;

 @SerializedName("company")
 private String company;

 @SerializedName("designation")
 private String designation;

 @SerializedName("thumbnail")
 private String thumbnail;

 @SerializedName("original_image")
 private String original_image;


 @SerializedName("speaker_info")
 private String speaker_info;

 @SerializedName("twitter_url")
 private String twitter_url;

 @SerializedName("linkdin_url")
 private String linkdin_url;

 @SerializedName("facebook_url")
 private String facebook_url;

 @SerializedName("last_sync_time")
 private long last_sync_time;

 public long getLast_sync_time() {
     return last_sync_time;
 }

 public void setLast_sync_time(long last_sync_time) {
     this.last_sync_time = last_sync_time;
 }

 public String getSpeaker_id() {
     return speaker_id;
 }

 public void setSpeaker_id(String speaker_id) {
     this.speaker_id = speaker_id;
 }

 public String getName() {
     return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
     this.name = name;
 }

 public String getDesignation() {
     return designation;
 }

 public void setDesignation(String designation) {
     this.designation = designation;
 }

 public String getCompany() {
     return company;
 }

 public void setCompany(String company) {
     this.company = company;
 }

 public String getThumbnail() {
     return thumbnail;
 }

 public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
     this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
 }

 public String getOriginal_image() {
     return original_image;
 }

 public void setOriginal_image(String original_image) {
     this.original_image = original_image;
 }

 public String getSpeaker_info() {
     return speaker_info;
 }

 public void setSpeaker_info(String speaker_info) {
     this.speaker_info = speaker_info;
 }

 public String getTwitter_url() {
     return twitter_url;
 }

 public void setTwitter_url(String twitter_url) {
     this.twitter_url = twitter_url;
 }

 public String getLinkdin_url() {
     return linkdin_url;
 }

 public void setLinkdin_url(String linkdin_url) {
     this.linkdin_url = linkdin_url;
 }

 public String getFacebook_url() {
     return facebook_url;
 }

 public void setFacebook_url(String facebook_url) {
     this.facebook_url = facebook_url;
 }

 public SpeakersBean(){

 }
 // Parcelling part
 public SpeakersBean(Parcel in){
     String[] data = new String[10];

     in.readStringArray(data);
     this.speaker_id = data[0];
     this.name = data[1];
     this.company = data[2];
     this.designation = data[3];
     this.thumbnail = data[4];
     this.original_image=data[5];
     this.speaker_info = data[6];
     this.twitter_url = data[7];
     this.linkdin_url = data[8];
     this.facebook_url = data[9];
 }

 @Override
 public int describeContents() {
     return 0;
 }

 @Override
 public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
     dest.writeStringArray(new String[] {this.speaker_id,
             this.name,
             this.company,
             this.designation,
             this.thumbnail,
             this.original_image,
             this.speaker_info,
             this.twitter_url,
             this.linkdin_url,
             this.facebook_url});
 }
 public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
     public SpeakersBean createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
         return new SpeakersBean(in);
     }
     public SpeakersBean[] newArray(int size) {
         return new SpeakersBean[size];
     }
 }; }
```

This is my Layout Resource file for connect

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >      <ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">
      <include
          android:id="@+id/customtoolbar"
          layout="@layout/customtoolbar_youtube" />

 <LinearLayout
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
 android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
 android:background="@color/dark_gray">
 <EditText
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:id="@+id/name"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="Name"/>
 <EditText
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:id="@+id/email"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="Email"/>
 <EditText
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:id="@+id/mobile"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="Mobile"/>
 <EditText
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:id="@+id/compny_name"
     android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:hint="Company Name"/>
 <Button
     android:id="@+id/connect"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:text="Submit"
     android:textColor="@color/white"
     android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/> </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Tell me how to use get and set here for `speaker_id`. As I do not understand the code I use it in connect class is here

```
   SpeakersBean sb_obj=new SpeakersBean();
    sb_obj = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("speaker");
    sb_obj.setSpeaker_id(sb_obj.getSpeaker_id().toString().trim());   
   //getting null
   // sb_obj.setSpeaker_id(s_id);
   //s_id =sb_obj.getSpeaker_id();
```

Comment: so you want to pass speaker_id along with the parameter

Comment: yes but i dont understand how to pass it.

Comment: if you want to pass it your server script should also mention about it. otherwise it will show error

Comment: ya it is mention in server script but i want to know how to pass it from here to server because without speaker_id that will give me volley server error.

Comment: are you getting value value in speaker_id or is it showing empty?

Comment: yes values for all the parameters i define in speakerbean class is coming from server as i use them in another class but in connect class when i am trying to use speaker_id it gives me null pointer exception please tell me how to get value here and pass it along with connect class parameters.

Comment: so in speaker_id your value is null so you are getting null pointer error.

Comment: yes please tell me how to pass it ,because as i have seen in some example before get it i need to set it. but i don't know how to use both get and set here?

Comment: to get value from server use GET method , then save it in some ArrayList then use the same Arraylist to send values using Post

Comment: i did that   sb_obj = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("speaker"); but getting null

Answer (score 0):

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-get-json-from-server/

try this
This use volley to get data and check if you are getting data

After that to post refer this

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-post-request-tutorial/

Comment: Yes i am geeting data from server

Comment: yes id too only i don't understand how to pass it with connect parameters

Comment: ok i think you save it in some Array or some where .Try to get value if from Array (using for loop). and place it to a string. Then us that string  params.put(KEY_ID, id); on the place of id

Comment: Actually problem is that value is coming from server but i do not use it anywhere in project or i had not save it somewhere the only use of this id is in post request.

Comment: i think you can't understand me. In order to get value in POST request you need to store the value from GET request